# InstallShield adds assemblies referenced but i dont want them

Tags: .net-3.5, installshield

When using InstallShield to create a compressed setup file, i noticed that InstallShield discovers referenced assemblies from files i added to Files and Folders and adds them to the setup.exe. While I am aware of those file I added I don't want to have those files in the setup too for file size issues.

Those said I can't find any property i could disable this.

Any ideas?
Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

InstallShield defaults new components to Properties and Dependencies.  You should set this to Properties Only.  Also you should go into Tools | Options | .NET and change the default.

As an aside, I think this pattern is soo horrible that I actually have a build automation step that looks through the build log for assemblies captured this way and force a build break.  It's not a very deterministic process and the scanner will frequently add stupid references like System.Windows.Forms.dll to the installer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the filters.xml file can be edited to prevent any specific assemblies from being added, but your point still stands.

Comment: True but that creates a CM nightmare on the build machine. Making sure you have the correct filters.xml is one more thing you have to automate or risk a build problem. Also I make extensive use of Merge Modules and this type of dependency scanning creates component rule violations.  Dependency scanning should never be used in Merge Module project types IMO.

Comment: 12 years later... in a .NET Core world it's crazy hard to know what's what making this even more impossible. 12 years ago I'd be upset if the installer added a BCL library.  Now in .NET 6 that might actually be the right thing to do.